# How to delete directory content that is older than one day with perl in crontab

Tags: command-line, cron, perl

As mentioned in title, i'm trying to delete files that are older than one day inside a directory with many many files (without actually deleting the said directory) - the directory is backed up by a remote rsnapshot server so i don't need the source files anymore as soon as they're backed up, the problem is that

```
find /directory/* -mtime +1 -delete
```

gives an error '**argument list too long**' since there are that many files (they're not even that big, it's just a lot of pictures and small videos from a security camera working with motion software - which is great by the way ;)

I've stumbled over this command that i could use with crontab:

```
perl -e 'for(<~/test1/*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'
```

but i don't really understand this command, as i understood it's some kind of loop. It did actually work on a test directory i created (test1 obviously) with a bunch of test files that were all **younger** than one day, i don't think that the 'older than' argument is even in here..

How would i go about that? Feel free to modify my question if it's not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` is recursive. You don't need to do `find /directory/*`, just use:

```
find /directory/ -mtime +1 -delete
```

Comment: @steeldriver I considered that.. then I realised that deleting something immediately inside the directory will change the mtime, and since `-delete` is depth-first, the directory itself will be last thing examined - so either it had some files deleted, and mtime ~now, or all files from <1day and mtime from the last file created (so <1day). Either way, the directory is safe.

Comment: Ahh... cunning ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, well it doesn't really work - tried it even with sudo - and no files are deleted at all (when searching the directory recursively, so without * at the end)..?? It seems to accept the command, but nothing really happens..

Comment: @deltagreen88 then it's not finding any files last modified two days ago

Comment: Ah, so the +1 is actually more than one day (f.ex one day is default, and the +1 means 2x in total)..?

Comment: @deltagreen88 yes, see the example for atime in find's manual

Comment: Ok, tried with -mmin +1440, which only deletes the directory itself, if there is not one single file that stands against the time argument; so if all the files are older than one day, the directory will be deleted as well (cause it's obviously older than one day), otherwise it works exactly how i wanted it to work, and since there will always be files newer than one day, i must not be afraid of the directory being deleted.. Eventually you could highlight that -mtime +1 is actually 2x days (as mentioned in the man find) which makes one use -mmin over -mtime.. Highly appreciated ;)

Comment: @deltagreen88 huh, in that case you can protect the directory: `find /directory -mindepth 1 ...`

Answer (score 0):

If `find /directory/* -mtime +1 -delete`  does produce the right files but just too long a list, what about:

> find /directory/* -mtime +1 | while read fName; do rm $fName;done

Or write the output to a file first and then process the file. Many roads lead to Rome... :)